# kubectl get nodes error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized) - how to fix

Tags: kubernetes

Without changes in infrastructure If I execute any kubectl command, ie:

```
kubectl get nodes
```

I get the error

```
You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

The kubernetes cluster was opperating ok and I did no changes to it... Any ideas how to debug this? kubectl has no -vv od debug flag to provide more information.

If i try

```
kubectl version

Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"17", GitVersion:"v1.17.0",
(...) 
error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)
```

Answer (score 19):

In my case the issue started after renewing kubernates certificates, this caused the existing `~/.kube/config` to have outdated keys and certificate values in it.

The solution was to replace the **values** `client-certificate-data` and `client-key-data` in file `~/.kube/config` with the values from the updated file in `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf` of the same name.

Comment: For me the new keys in `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf` had paths to the pem files. I had to do `sudo base64 -w 0 /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem` and paste the output of that into `~/.kube/config` for the matching keys.

Answer (score 16):

You can copy the `client-certificate-data` and `client-key-data` from `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` to your `~/.kube/config` file as of more recent versions of Kubernetes. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49886394/872949) for determining when your certificates expire.

Comment: Worked on 1.21.1

Answer (score 9):

I have faced the similar issue today and the above comments helped me to fix the issue. I am adding more details with my scenario because it might be helpful for the people which have similar settings.

I have a separate user for connecting to my k8s cluster (It's a normal cluster in EC2 instances). I had created the user arunlal with limited access by adding ClusterRoleBindings.

If you get the following error while running API to cluster (in my case Kubectl):

```
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
```

**Go through the following order.**

**- First check the cert used in your config file (local client)**

I had a separate configuration on my local system, because the main config had the details about the other k8s & okd cluster credentials. So I had created second configuration on my Laptop (/Users/arunlal/.kube/config_two). In this case I have the following aliases:

```
alias kctl="kubectl --kubeconfig=/Users/arunlal/.kube/config_two"
```

**- From this file you will get the cert that we are using.**

```
[arunlal.as@crybit.com ~] cat /Users/arunlal/.kube/config_two| grep -A 5 users
users:
- name: arunlal
  user:
    client-certificate: /Users/arunlal/.arunlal-keys/arunlal.crt
    client-key: /Users/arunlal/.arunlal-keys/arunlal.key
```

**- Once you get the cert in your client configuration you can check the validity using the openssl command.**

```
    [arunlal.as@crybit.com ~] openssl x509 -noout -dates -in /Users/arunlal/.arunlal-keys/arunlal.crt
    notBefore=Jun 22 23:43:22 2021 GMT
    notAfter=Sep 30 23:43:22 2021 GMT
```

**- Validate the expiry**

While creating the user I passed the days as 5, that was the issue. How I created user?

```
openssl genrsa -out arunlal.key 2048
openssl req -new -key arunlal.key -out arunlal.csr -subj "/CN=arunlal/O=crybit"
openssl x509 -req -in arunlal.csr -CA /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt -CAkey /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out arunlal.crt -days 5
kubectl config set-credentials arunlal --client-certificate=/root/arunlal-keys/arunlal.crt  --client-key=/root/arunlal-keys/arunlal.key
```

**- To fix, I recreated the cert with more number of days**

```
openssl x509 -req -in arunlal.csr -CA /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt
-CAkey /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key -CAcreateserial -out arunlal.crt -days 100
```

**- This we need to run from the k8s cluster.**

**- Replaced the cert locally.**

```
Modified /Users/arunlal/.arunlal-keys/arunlal.crt with new cert.
```

Hope this will help someone. Thanks!

~ arun

Answer (score 9):

I got the same after updating certificates:

`kubeadm alpha certs renew all`

And then I had to follow

```
$ cd ~/.kube

# Archive the old config file containing the out of date certificates
$ mv config conf.archive.2021

# Copy the new configuration file created using kubeadm
$ cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf config

# apply permissions to your current admin user and group
$ sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) config
```

Kubernetes version : `1.19`

[Reference](https://www.oak-tree.tech/blog/k8s-cert-yearly-renewwal)

Comment: how to known the certificate expired?@Sachith Muhandiram

Comment: @Dolphin, `kubeadm certs check-expiration`

Answer (score 3):

The kubeconfig certificate may have changed. If you deployed your cluster using terraform. Do terraform apply to generate a new kubeconfig file.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was using a cluster created by kOps and cluster admin user with credentials (~/.kube/config) generated by: `kops export kubeconfig --admin`

By default the credentials expire after 18 hours. So another:

```
kops export kubeconfig --admin
```

Did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - after all the cert has changed. Check your ~/.kube/config if you have this

Comment: What did you change in ~/kube/config? And why would certificates change?

Comment: no idea... but it was very small difference

Comment: how do you figure out the right cert?

Comment: compared the cert with backup files I had. No idea how it got corrupted

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting "error: You must be logged in to the server (the server has asked for the client to provide credentials)" in Azure Kubernetes service.

I fixed this with trying to connect and executed the command mentioned on the Connect to ClusterName.

```
az account set --subscription de81a6e3-1784-4732-9282-XXXXXXXX7
az aks get-credentials --resource-group resourceGroupName --name clusterName
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by deleting minikube

```
minikube delete 
minikube start --vm-driver=none
```

Answer (score 0):

After renewing your certs you need to apply the new certs to the admin config for kubectl to work.

The following takes a backup of your existing config, and applies the new admin config.

```sh
cp /root/.kube/config /root/.kube/.old-$(date --iso)-config
cp /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf /root/.kube/config
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case using AWS EKS what solved the problem was:

```
aws eks --region <region code> update-kubeconfig --name <cluster name>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in AWS eks. I created cluster by cloudformation and then tried to connect from instance with different role.

By default only USER/role that was used to create eks cluster is permitted to connect to eks. It is controlled by kubernetes config map with name: aws-auth (iam role that give permission for instance to connect Kubernetes need to be configured not only in aws IAM but also in eks config map.....).
For example if I created cluster from cloudformations not by jenkins then I was needed to add jenkins role in aws-auth config map to be able to connect jenkins to cluster:

```
mapRoles: |
  - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::XXXXXXXXXXXX:role/testrole
    username: testrole
    groups:
      - system:masters
```

This helped me:
https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/eks-api-server-unauthorized-error

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this command to troubleshoot issues with your current certificate. This command reads the client-certificate-data from your kubeconfig file, decodes it, and then uses OpenSSL to display the details:

```
grep 'client-certificate-data' $HOME/.kube/config | \
awk '{print $2}' | base64 -d | openssl x509 -text
```

Credit goes [to this blog post](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2018/06/12/examining-x509-certificates-embedded-in-kubeconfig-files/) by Scott Lowe for the original information.

Answer (score 0):

It means in the aws-auth file the role is missing from which you are logged in.
In my case, someone else created a cluster and when I created a new bastion host it threw the same error. When I edited the role in the aws-auth file it worked.
Now the question is how can I access the aws-auth file? It was a public cluster you can access it through AWS Cloudshell. In Cloudshell type command eksctl edit configmap and edit your role. then you must be able to access the cluster.